# Unable to properly access additional fields on junction table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Apologies if this is obvious as I don't have much experience with sequelize yet. I am trying to get a field that is in the junction table CustomerContact. Currently I am getting a contact and then retrieving its attached customers

```
const contactList: Contact[] = await db()
        .Contact.newActiveScope()
        .withCustomers()
        .findAll();
```

```
const mainCustomer: Customer = contactList[i].getMainCustomer();

const mainCustomerContacts = mainCustomer && mainCustomer?.customerContacts;
const thisCustomerContactRole = mainCustomerContacts?.find((c) => c.contactId === contact.id)?.role;
```

Outputting the `mainCustomer` gets me the following information

```
{
id: 'a94fd13a-1fdd-11ec-a12c-121c563gb2f5',
accountName: 'Test Tests',
CustomerContact: { role: 1, relationship: 2, status: 'active' }
}
```

I want to use the properties in `CustomerContact`, but trying to access it gives me a typescript error, saying `CustomerContact` does not exist on type `ContactWithCustomerContactStatic`, which has the following shape.

```
export  type  ContactWithCustomerContactStatic = Partial<Customer> &
Pick<CustomerContact, 'role' | 'relationship'>;
```

I associate the Customer in the Contact Model

```
this.belongsToMany(Customer, {
    as:  'customers',
    foreignKey:  'contactId',
    otherKey:  'customerId',
    through:  CustomerContact  as  CustomerContactStatic,
});
this.addScope('withCustomers', {
    include: [
        {
            as:  'customers',
            model:  Customer  as  CustomerStatic,
            where: { isArchived:  false },
            required:  false,
        },
    ],
});
```

and vice versa

```
Customer.belongsToMany(Contact, {
    as:  'contacts',
    through:  CustomerContact,
    foreignKey:  'customerId',
    otherKey:  'contactId',
});
  
Customer.addScope('contacts', () => ({
include: [
    {
        as:  'contacts',
        attributes: ['id', 'firstName', 'lastName'],
        model: (Contact  as  ContactStatic).newScope(),
        required:  false,
        through: {
            where: { status:  CustomerContactStatus.active },
        },
    },
],
}));
```

I can technically retrieve the values, but the typescript error gives me pause.

I'm positive I'm missing something but having trouble determining what that something is. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Typescript is showing this error because of the way you are declaring the ContactWithCustomerContactStatic type.

```
export  type  ContactWithCustomerContactStatic = Partial<Customer> &
Pick<CustomerContact, 'role' | 'relationship'>;
```

When declaring this way you say to Typescript that ContactWithCustomerContactStatic type has the following shape

```
interface ContactWithCustomerContactStatic {
  // all properties from Customer interface comes here
  role // it's in the root
  relationship // it's also in the root
}
```

But, they are not in the root of the object, given the output that you presented

```
{
  id: 'a94fd13a-1fdd-11ec-a12c-121c563gb2f5',
  accountName: 'Test Tests',
  CustomerContact: { role: 1, relationship: 2, status: 'active' }
}
```

This should work

```
type ContactWithCustomerContactStatic = Partial<Customer> 
& { customerContact: Pick<CustomerContact, 'role' | 'relationship'> 
}
```